# graphql with sequelize join foreign key

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql

I made simple board api system with graphql.

And I use sequelize(version 4) for connect to database.

[schema.graphql]

```
type Article {
    article_no: Int!
    subject: String!
    content: String!
    createdAt: String!
    updatedAt: String!
    comment: String
}

type Comment {
    article_no: Int!
    content: String!,
    createdAt: String!
}

type Query {
    articles: [Article]!
    article(article_no: Int!): Article
    comments: [Comment]!
    comment(article_no: Int!): Comment
}

type Mutation {
    createArticle(subject: String!, content: String!, password: String!): Boolean!
    createComment(article_no: Int!, content: String!, password: String!): Boolean!
}
```

[resolvers.js]

```
import { Article, Comment } from './db';

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        articles: async () => {
            return Article.all();
        },
        article: async(_, args) => {
            return Article.find({
                where: args.article_no,
            });
        },
        comments: async () => {
            return Comment.all();
        },
        comment: async(_, args) => {
            return Comment.find({
                where: args.article_no
            });
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        createArticle: async (_, args) => {
            try {
                const article = await Article.create({
                    subject: args.subject,
                    content: args.content,
                    password: args.password
                });
                return true;
            } catch(e) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        createComment: async(_, args) => {
            try {
                const comment = await Comment.create({
                    article_no: args.article_no,
                    content: args.content,
                    password: args.password
                })
                return comment;
            } catch(e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

export default resolvers;
```

[db.js]

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
import config from '../config/config';

const db = new Sequelize(config.DB, config.USER, config.PASS, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
})

export const Article = db.define('article', {
    article_no: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    subject: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
    },
    comment: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
})

export const Comment = db.define('comment', {
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(150),
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
})

Article.hasMany(Comment, {
    foreignKey: 'article_no',
    scope: {
        comment: 'comment'
    }
})
Comment.belongsTo(Article, {
    foreignKey: 'article_no',
    targetKey: 'article_no',
    allowNull: false,
    as: 'comment'
});
db.sync()
.then(console.log('[*] DB Sync Done'))
```

`Article` and `Comment` is 1:N realtionship.

So I set `hasMany` to `Article` and set `belongsTo` to `Comment`.

Also Comment as comment and include it to Article's scope.

But when I request query `{ article(id:1) { subject, comment } }`,

comment return null.

I refer document http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#foreign-keys and follow as well.

But it doesn't work.

My Expected result is here:

```
{
  "data": {
    "article": {
      "subject": "test",
      "comment": {
           "article_no":1,
           "content: "first comment",
           "created_at": "2018010101001",
           # every comment related article is here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Current result is here:

```
{
  "data": {
    "article": {
      "subject": "test",
      "comment": null
    }
  }
}
```

I want to display all the comments that related specific article.

Is there any solution about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of notes to get you on the right track:

When defining a relationship, keep in mind that the model whose method you are calling is the one that you are effectively adding a property to. For example, if you call `Article.hasMany(Comment)`, this will create a `comments` property on the `Article` model and will affect the `Comment` model. Likewise, calling `Comment.belongsTo(Article)` will create an `article` property on the `Comment` model and not affect the `Article` model.

Note that even if the relationship is created, if you want to *include* the associated comments when you query an article (or vice versa), you must pass in the appropriate `include` option. This can be done directly in the query call, i.e.

```
Article.findAll({ include: [Comment] })
```

or can be part of a scope, like the default scope. Scopes can be set as part of the model's definition, or added after the fact by calling `addScope`. For example, you could do:

```
Article.addScope('defaultScope', {
  include: [Comment],
}, { override: true })
```

Note: The `override` here is necessary because the default scope already exists. To query the associated models, your query call or the scope you're using must include the appropriate `include` array. Associations also have the idea of "scope" but it's different from a model's scope. See the docs [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/scopes.html#associations) for a discussion of the differences.

Lastly, when passing a `where` option to your `find` call, you should make sure it includes the property names you want to query against, i.e.

```
Article.find({ where: { article_no: args.article_no } })

// or possibly even
Article.find({ where: args })
```

Comment: You said `if you call Article.hasMany(Comment), this will create a comments property on the Article model and will affect the Comment model`. But after I check the database, there is no additional column. So I think, additional column doesn't apply to real database, right?

Comment: And, should I set both `Article.hasMany(Comment)` and `Comment.belongsTo(Article)` in 1:N relationship? Or just set one relationship between that?

Comment: If I remember correctly, either `hasMany` or `belongsTo` should create the appropriate column (in this case in the articles table). Whether you use one or the other, or both depends on, again, whether you need your Article model instance to have a `comments` property or you need your Comments model instance to have an `article` property (or both).

Comment: FWIW, when using `sequelize.sync()` you may need to set the `force` option to true to see your changes applied to your db (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with your graphql schema, and your sequelize schema...

Lets look at your graphql schema

```
type Article {
    ...
    comment: String
}
```

You wrote that Article and Comment have a 1:M relation
but here the comment field is of type string and not even an array of string

the correct type definition for Article should be (imo):

```
type Article {
    ...
    comments: [Comment] 
}
```

now if you make the adjustments to your sequelize schema that @Daniel-Rearden
wrote in his answer your `Article` model should have a `comments` property so it will be returned by default from the `default resolver` of the `Article` type

Comment: `Comment[]` is throw errors `Syntax Error: Expected Name, found [`. Maybe `[Comment]` is correct way.